# how to convert xml to avro without ignoring !CDATA content?

Tags: java, xml, avro, jackson-dataformat-avro

I have the following source XML file named customers.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p:CustomerElement xmlns:p="http://www.dog.com/customer" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:schemaLocation="http://www.dog.com/customer Customer.xsd">
  <Customer>
    <Sender>
      <transmitDate>2016-02-21T00:00:00</transmitDate>
      <transmitter>Dog ETL v2.0</transmitter>
      <dealerCode><![CDATA[P020]]></dealerCode>
      <DMSSystem><![CDATA[DBS]]></DMSSystem>
      <DMSReleaseNumber><![CDATA[5.0]]></DMSReleaseNumber>
    </Sender>
    <Identifier>
      <updateInd><![CDATA[A]]></updateInd>
      <dealerCustNumber><![CDATA[AMADOR]]></dealerCustNumber>
      <dealerCustName><![CDATA[AMADOR COMPUTERS]]></dealerCustName>
      <phoneNumber><![CDATA[800 111 4444]]></phoneNumber>
      <faxNumber><![CDATA[780 111 4444]]></faxNumber>
      <email xsi:nil="true" />
      <customerType><![CDATA[R]]></customerType>
      <activeCustomerInd>false</activeCustomerInd>
      <parentCustomerNumber xsi:nil="true" />
      <primaryStoreNumber><![CDATA[00]]></primaryStoreNumber>
      <preferredLanguage><![CDATA[ENG]]></preferredLanguage>
      <dealerDateInSystem>2000-01-11T00:00:00</dealerDateInSystem>
      <dealerLastUpdatedDate>2015-02-05T00:00:00</dealerLastUpdatedDate>
    </Identifier>
    <Location>
      <address2><![CDATA[ACCOUNT FLAGGED FOR DELETION]]></address2>
      <address3><![CDATA[AS PER BILL  FEB AA/15]]></address3>
      <city><![CDATA[CHICAGO]]></city>
      <postalCode><![CDATA[Q5S 1E5]]></postalCode>
      <state><![CDATA[AB]]></state>
      <country><![CDATA[CA]]></country>
      <location><![CDATA[FLAGGED FOR DELETION]]></location>
      <addressType><![CDATA[M]]></addressType>
    </Location>
    <Division>
      <divisionCode><![CDATA[G]]></divisionCode>
      <divisionName><![CDATA[CAR]]></divisionName>
      <IndustryCode>
        <industryCode><![CDATA[AQ99]]></industryCode>
        <primaryIndustryCodeInd>true</primaryIndustryCodeInd>
      </IndustryCode>
      <SalesRep>
        <number><![CDATA[XXX]]></number>
        <name><![CDATA[KILL ACCOUNT IN PROCESS]]></name>
        <type><![CDATA[M]]></type>
        <par>0</par>
        <email xsi:nil="true" />
        <phoneNumber><![CDATA[000 000 0000]]></phoneNumber>
      </SalesRep>
    </Division>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <Sender>
      <transmitDate>2016-02-21T00:00:00</transmitDate>
      <transmitter>Dog ETL v2.0</transmitter>
      <dealerCode><![CDATA[P000]]></dealerCode>
      <DMSSystem><![CDATA[DBS]]></DMSSystem>
      <DMSReleaseNumber><![CDATA[5.0]]></DMSReleaseNumber>
    </Sender>
    <Identifier>
      <updateInd><![CDATA[A]]></updateInd>
      <dealerCustNumber><![CDATA[UU20888]]></dealerCustNumber>
      <dealerCustName><![CDATA[ ADVERTISING AND PR]]></dealerCustName>
      <phoneNumber xsi:nil="true" />
      <faxNumber xsi:nil="true" />
      <email xsi:nil="true" />
      <customerType><![CDATA[I]]></customerType>
      <activeCustomerInd>true</activeCustomerInd>
      <parentCustomerNumber xsi:nil="true" />
      <primaryStoreNumber><![CDATA[M2]]></primaryStoreNumber>
      <preferredLanguage><![CDATA[ENG]]></preferredLanguage>
      <dealerDateInSystem>2015-11-18T00:00:00</dealerDateInSystem>
      <dealerLastUpdatedDate>2015-11-19T00:00:00</dealerLastUpdatedDate>
    </Identifier>
    <Location>
      <address2><![CDATA[EQUIP]]></address2>
      <city><![CDATA[ADER]]></city>
      <country><![CDATA[CA]]></country>
      <addressType><![CDATA[M]]></addressType>
    </Location>
    <Division>
      <divisionCode><![CDATA[A]]></divisionCode>
      <divisionName><![CDATA[AGRO]]></divisionName>
      <IndustryCode>
        <industryCode><![CDATA[EQ00]]></industryCode>
        <primaryIndustryCodeInd>true</primaryIndustryCodeInd>
      </IndustryCode>
    </Division>
  </Customer>
</p:CustomerElement>
```

I have the following java code, which parses customers.xml into individual "Customer" entities, and then attempts to convert each of them into an AVRO format:

```
package com.dogsoft.data.xmltoavro;

import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.regexp.joni.constants.NodeType;
import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import org.apache.avro.Protocol;
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader;
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericArray;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.util.Utf8;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class ParseXmlFile {

    private static Protocol protocol;

    public static void xmlToAvro(File xmlFile, File avroFile) throws IOException, SAXException {
        try {
            InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("/tmp/xml.avsc");
            if (stream == null) throw new IllegalStateException("Classpath should include xml.avsc");

            protocol = Protocol.parse(stream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        Schema schema = protocol.getType("Element");

        Document doc = parse(xmlFile);
        DatumWriter<GenericRecord> datumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(schema);

        try (DataFileWriter<GenericRecord> fileWriter = new DataFileWriter<>(datumWriter)) {
            fileWriter.create(schema, avroFile);
            Object docElement = doc.getDocumentElement();
            fileWriter.append(wrapElement(doc.getDocumentElement()));

        }
    }

    private static GenericData.Record wrapElement(Element el) {
        GenericData.Record record = new GenericData.Record(protocol.getType("Element"));
        record.put("name", el.getNodeName());

        NamedNodeMap attributeNodes = el.getAttributes();
        List<GenericData.Record> attrRecords = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < attributeNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Attr attr = (Attr) attributeNodes.item(i);
            attrRecords.add(wrapAttr(attr));
        }
        record.put("attributes", attrRecords);

        List<Object> childArray = new ArrayList<>();
        NodeList childNodes = el.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = childNodes.item(i);
            Object nt = node.getNodeType();
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                childArray.add(wrapElement((Element) node));

            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
                childArray.add(node.getTextContent());

        }
        record.put("children", childArray);

        return record;
    }

    private static GenericData.Record wrapAttr(Attr attr) {
        GenericData.Record record = new GenericData.Record(protocol.getType("Attribute"));

        record.put("name", attr.getName());
        record.put("value", attr.getValue());

        return record;
    }

    private static Document parse(File file) throws IOException, SAXException {
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            return builder.parse(file);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void avroToXml(File avroFile, File xmlFile) throws IOException {
        try {
            InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("/tmp/xml.avsc");
            if (stream == null) throw new IllegalStateException("Classpath should include xml.avsc");

            protocol = Protocol.parse(stream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        DatumReader<GenericRecord> datumReader = new GenericDatumReader<>(protocol.getType("Element"));
        DataFileReader<GenericRecord> dataFileReader = new DataFileReader<>(avroFile, datumReader);

        GenericRecord record = dataFileReader.next();

        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        Element el = unwrapElement(record, doc);
        doc.appendChild(el);

        saveDocument(doc, xmlFile);
    }

    private static Element unwrapElement(GenericRecord record, Document doc) {
        String name = "" + record.get("name");
        Element el = doc.createElement(name);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        GenericArray<GenericRecord> attrArray = (GenericArray<GenericRecord>) record.get("attributes");
        for (GenericRecord attrRecord : attrArray)
            el.setAttributeNode(unwrapAttr(attrRecord, doc));

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        GenericArray<Object> childArray = (GenericArray<Object>) record.get("children");
        for (Object childObj : childArray) {
            if (childObj instanceof GenericRecord)
                el.appendChild(unwrapElement((GenericRecord) childObj, doc));

            if (childObj instanceof Utf8)
                el.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("" + childObj));
        }

        return el;
    }

    private static Attr unwrapAttr(GenericRecord record, Document doc) {
        Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("" + record.get("name"));
        attr.setValue("" + record.get("value"));
        return attr;
    }

    private static void saveDocument(Document doc, File file) {
        try {
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();

            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(file));
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Object nodeObject = null;
        Node myNode = null;
        Transformer transformer = null;

        try
        {
            try {
                transformer =
                        TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse("/tmp/customers.xml");
            System.out.printf("Version = %s%n", doc.getXmlVersion());
            System.out.printf("Encoding = %s%n", doc.getXmlEncoding());
            System.out.printf("Standalone = %b%n%n", doc.getXmlStandalone());
            if (doc.hasChildNodes())
            {
                int customerNumber = 0;
                NodeList nl = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = nl.item(i);
                    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        System.out.println(node.toString());
                        customerNumber++;
                        File avroFile = new File("/tmp/customer" + customerNumber + ".avro");
                        File xmlFile = new File("/tmp/customer" + customerNumber + ".xml");
                        File xmlFile1 = new File("/tmp/customer" + customerNumber + "-foo.xml");
                        try {
                            transformer.transform(
                                    new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(xmlFile));
                            File outputFile = new File("/tmp/customer" + customerNumber + ".avro");
                            xmlToAvro(xmlFile, outputFile);

                        } catch (TransformerException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            System.err.println("IOE: " + ioe);
        }
        catch (SAXException saxe)
        {
            System.err.println("SAXE: " + saxe);
        }
        catch (FactoryConfigurationError fce)
        {
            System.err.println("FCE: " + fce);
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException pce)
        {
            System.err.println("PCE: " + pce);
        }
    }
}
```

This code works overall, but it ignores any content, which is enclosed into

```
![CDATA[
```

tag. As it happens, most of the actual useful data in the customers.xml files is enclosed into these tags.

Is there a way to modify this code, to make it not ignore the CDATA contents?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hand-writing parser code, you might want to split the problem in two parts: first, bind XML into POJO (using JAXB or Jackson XML module); and then write POJO as Avro (using Apache Avro lib, or Jackson Avro module). All you need for that would be POJO definition that matches expected structure for data as XML and Avro. Result should be less code, and basically specifying what needs to happen and now how to do it.