# Serialize in Avro without having a schema

Tags: java, avro

I'm writing a component that needs to change format from XML to AVRO. I don't want to change this component (rebuild it) every time the XML schema changes - I would like the output to be AVRO but without using a schema.

Is that possible at all?

Comment: See related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40918257/how-to-convert-xml-to-avro-without-ignoring-cdata-content

Comment: The [Avro specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#Data+Serialization) says "Avro data is always serialized with its schema".